# Local Prerendering not worked

Tags: angularjs, node.js, prerender

I want to use [prerender.io](https://prerender.io) , according to [it's Documentation](https://prerender.io/documentation/test-it)

after

Run these commands

```
$git clone https://github.com/prerender/prerender.git
$cd prerender
$npm install
$node server.js
```

If I visit  `MY_SERVER_IP:3000/http://www.google.com`  It have to show prerendered version of google.com at there, **but** when I try to see it  browser tab getting on loading  and in `server.js` I only see

```
 2016-11-29T18:01:11.978Z getting http://www.google.com/
```

without any result in browser.

Where is the problem?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you aren't seeing "started phantom", which you should see after it's started correctly. If you are still running into an issue here, check to make sure all of your dependencies installed correctly.

Comment: @Prerender.io thanks for your reply, ye it was , I resolved this issue with adding not valid region TAG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because locale problem on phantomjs

According to [this issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12835)try to resolve it with

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

- Stop server.js
- resolve local warning
- logout ( or terminate your session to changing locales takes effect)
- start server.js again